# Using Blowfish Encryption within .NET

Tags: c#, encryption, blowfish

I am working on a project where I need to undertake Blowfish encryption and decryption. Is there anything out there that others are using to do this within  but cannot find anything within a .NET C# environment?

I would ideally like something does not rely on running an exe as this will eventually live on a live server where exe’s are bared!

I have read some of the older posts on SO but nothing suitable.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You can find a c# implementation of the blowfish algorithm [**here**](http://web.archive.org/web/20101219013038/http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidD5E0D7AC50858EA8F7131E8CD2746F3471A1B953.aspx).

Comment: Have you got a really good reason for not using .NETs built in AES encryption?

Comment: It is beeing forced upon us by our customer. So we are sort of stuck with it.

Comment: [Implementation in a single .cs file](https://defuse.ca/blowfish.htm)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to look at http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/

It's an open source project (MIT License to be precise) that gives APIs for encryption, including BlowFish