# using .c files in C# (winform .net)

Tags: c#, .net, c, winforms, cryptography

I am using visual studio 2010 
my project is that,
 i want to encrypt text using blowfish algorithm and then add that encrypted data must be saved in my database

my blowfish algorthim is in .c file
my input must be taken via C# (windows form)
and my database is in sql server 2008

i just want to known that can i send the text taken via windows form (.net c#) to my .c file and proccess it and get that encrypted data and save that data in sql server via windows form

can this be done
please help me out

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Blowfish Encryption within .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681505/using-blowfish-encryption-within-net)

Comment: good one bro thanxx but the .c file must be compulsory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is called interop and it can be done in various ways. One of them is called Pinvoke - you create a DLL that exports the function you want to call from c# and pinvoke will take care of the rest. I suggest you read about it in microsoft's docs.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to compile the .c file into a DLL, and then you could use [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to create a C# binding to it

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use C++/CLI as intermediary between your C and C#

C# -> C++/CLI -> C

other way is to expose your C functions and use P/Invoke in C#.

Comment: The first choice (using C++/CLI) is less portable, since, AFAIK, the only C++/CLI compiler available is Visual Studio's