# Security.Encryption.Cryptography equivalent of blowfish?

Tags: c#, cryptography

I am interfacing with an old system that uses blowfish encryption... I really don't trust downloading precompiled dll's that I cant verify source code on. so going through the 
System.Security.Cryptography namespace blowfish is the only one I do not see listed...

can anyone point me in the right direction for encrypting/decrypting a blowfish string (given the encryption key is provided)

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681505/using-blowfish-encryption-within-net

Comment: The BCL doesn't contain a Blowfish implementation. So you'll need to use a third party implementation. Concerning your fear of pre-compiled `.dll`s, just use an open source implementation like BouncyCastle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is possibly BouncyCastle... Funny name, useful library. It is a 3rd party DLL however it is widely used and known to work correctly, and is open source if you'd like to verify the code yourself. Consider giving it a try!

[The Legion of the Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp)