# Decrypting a base64 encoded string

Tags: c#, base64, blowfish

I am encrypting a string using Setup Factory:

```
string Crypto.BlowfishEncryptString ( 
  string Text,
  string Key,
  number LineLen = 0 )
```

**Description**:

Blowfish encrypts a string and returns a base64-encoded string containing the encrypted data.

> Note: Base64 encoding is the process of encoding arbitrary data as
>   plain ASCII text. One common use for this type of encoding is sending
>   files through email. It is one of the techniques employed by the MIME
>   standard to send data other than plain ASCII text.

I wrote this:

```
encryptedPass = Crypto.BlowfishEncryptString("password123", "uniqueKey", 0);
```

Which prints a base-64 string:

```
j5b+4W25ugGZxXJZ0HCFxw==
```

Now to decrypt the password, in C#:

Using [the snippet available for .NET here](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/235342/blowfish-encryption-implementation-in-net).

```
string enKey = "uniqueKey";
string test = "j5b+4W25ugGZxXJZ0HCFxw==";

byte[] convertedByte = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(test);
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(convertedByte).Replace("-", string.Empty);

Blowfish algo = new Blowfish(enKey);
string decryptedTxt = algo.decryptString(hex);
```

But this returns null, I tried it without decoding the base-64 as well.

EDIT:

Tried decoding the base-64 string as well:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(test);
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", string.Empty);

Blowfish algo = new Blowfish(enKey);
string decryptedTxt = algo.decryptString(hex);
```

Comment: One of the comments on that project page says: *The encrypted output changes with each execution with the same inputs.* If that is true, this is a horrible implementation of Blowfish and you might want to search for another one.

Comment: @dotNET That sounds horrible, but Im stuck with using this. Is there a way out?

Comment: Related question, they recomend a different blowfish implementation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681505/using-blowfish-encryption-within-net

Comment: @bradbury9 been there, done that. none worked.

Comment: A bad company has got two solutions: Change the company or leave the company. Your call! :)

Comment: "_Im_ _stuck_ _with_ _using_ _this_" you are stuck using an unreliable code? Try other alternatives...